# Restricted integer composition, where every summand belongs to a different set

Tags: combinatorics

Could I get any suggestion on how to calculate the number of restricted integer compositions of a number $n$ with $k$ parts, where every summand belongs has its own subset?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^k \pi_i = n
\end{equation}
with every $\pi_i \in S_i$

Am I wrong if I imagine that rather than an expression, I would need to solve it numerically?

For example, with $\pi_1 \in \{1,2, 5, 6\}$, $\pi_2 \in \{7,13,14,16\}$ and $\pi_3 \in \{17,18, 21, 23\}$, how many combinations are there such that $\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=36$ (obviously the dimension of the actual problem is much higher).

Comment: what are the subsets $S_i$?

Comment: $S_i$ are subsets of nonnegative and non consecutive integer numbers with the same cardinality for all of them. I have edited the post with an example